# C# Serialization skipping xsi:nil="true" if other attributes provided in custom object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, null

I'm not sure I've pinpointed the problem but it appears my C# XML Serialization is skipping adding the "xsi:nil='true' if there are either (and I'm not sure which or how to solve)

1. Other attributes are provided or
2. It's a custom object

For example,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Custom", IsNullable = true)]
public customDataType Custom
{
        get { return this.privateCustomField; }
        set { this.privateCustomField= value; }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.namespace.org")]
public partial class customDataType
{
    private string attrField;
    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string AttrField
    {
        get { return this.attrField; }
        set { this.attrField= value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.valueField; }
        set { this.valueField = value;}
    }
}
```

---

Then in my class I create:

```
    Custom mycustom = new Custom();
    mycustom.AttrField = "7701003";
```

and that's it (I don't provide a *Value*). When I serialize my object, I get XML which looks like:

**<Custom AttrField="7701003"/>**

I'd like to see 
**<Custom xsi:nil="true" AttrField="7701003"/>**

That is, I don't get the nil="true" added. I"m not sure because of the custom data type (instead of int or string as I've seen online) or the fact there's an attribute.

The classes I'm using were created from an XSD using XSD.exe 4.0.30319.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The automatic class generation never works without editing the classes.  Try this

```
    [XmlRoot("Custom")]
    public class Custom
    {
        [XmlElement("CustomDataType")]
        public CustomDataType customDataType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("CustomDataType")]
    public partial class CustomDataType
    {
        [XmlAttribute("AttrField")]
        public string attrField { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Value")]]
        public string value {get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't end up using the above so I don't know if that works. I appreciate the answer. Due to the size of the class generation (the size of the XSD is reason I used it to begin with) I could not edit all the objects in time for the project completion.

This is unanswered at the moment.